# DDD - Aggregate inheritance vs composition, how to correctly design this situation?

Tags: inheritance, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I'm working on a PIM system. There is one Aggregate root Product which has attribute, productType (Meal, Grocery),name, image etc.. but as you know some product types as pharmacy are coming to  our system. Actually; meal and grocery product are very different properties.

If I implement meal and grocery complex objects in product class (composition), this pattern is shown fit the DDD aggregate root but there is a problem that  using Open/Close prensiple when pharmacy product is coming to our aggregate

```
public   class Product extends BaseAggregate<Long> {
    private String description;
    private Status status;
    private Long categoryId;
    private ArrayList<String> medias;
    private Grocery Grocery;
    private Meal Meal;

    public Product(description,status,categoryId,...){
      description=description;
      ...
    }
    
    public setStatusAsPassive(){ status=Status.Passive }

    .... (Rich Model)....
}
```

If I implement using inheritance and it is shown below

```
public  abstract class Product extends BaseAggregate<Long> {
    private String description;
    private Status status;
    private Long categoryId;
    public ArrayList<String> medias;
    protected abstract Channel getChannel();

    public Product(description,status,categoryId,...){
      description=description;
      ...
    }
    
    public setStatusAsPassive(){ status=Status.Passive }

    .... (Rich Model)....

}

public class GroceryProduct extends Product {

    private Long brandId;
    public Double desi;
    public Weight weight;
    public CatalogType catalogType; 
    public Catalog catalog;  //?
    private Boolean isAutoApprovable;
    private String   barcode;

    @Override
    protected Channel getChannel() {
        return Channel.MEAL;
    }

  public GroceryProduct(description,status,categoryId,...){
       super(description)
       ...
    }

  .... (Rich Model)....
}

public class MealProduct extends Product {

    public Boolean ownSellable;
    public Boolean upsellOffer;
    public ProductType productType;
    public Attribute attribute;


    @Override
    protected Channel getChannel() {
        return Channel.MEAL;
    }

   public MealProduct(description,status,categoryId,...){
       super(description)
       ...
    }
   .... (Rich Model)....

}
```

If I implement aggregate root with inheritance, how can I manage domain model? Is it correct?  This implementation  does not seem to known Tactical DDD, Rich Domain model. Even though Product is aggregate root, the rich domain model and service  differs in some place in terms of grocery and meal model. Even if I implement a single product repository, I still control using if meal or grocery.

which case should I use? inheritance vs composition